# Network communication slowdown after setting gateway on linux

Tags: linux, networking, gateway

We have two computers in local network, which need to communicate via TCP/IP.
Communication is working regularly until we set up the gateway; TCP communication is much slower (takes 10-20 seconds for sending and receiving ~16 bytes messages) after that, and we don't know why.
Their network settings from /etc/network/interfaces files are:

- First one is an at91sam9260 witch linux 2.6.33:

auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 172.20.52.232
broadcast 172.20.52.255
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 172.20.52.225

- Second one is Intel atom with debian squeeze:

auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.20.52.231
broadcast 172.20.52.255
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 172.20.52.225

We've tried pinging the devices with and without gateways, and it works fine. Also, traceroute works in both cases. The problem persists with and without other computers being present in the network, including the actual gateway. We've tried connecting the two devices directly, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: This is a weird one - it should definitely work from the configs above.  Are you running any kind of window manager or network manager on either of the boxes which is "overriding" the config ?  Is the assumption that there are no other nics (or bridge devices) in the PC's ?

Comment: We are not using any window manager, graphics is reduced to x11 server and a single java application on the machine with debian squeeze. The other one (at91sam9260) has no graphical server whatsoever. Also, no additional network manager software was installed on either of the machines.  
I didn't understood the question about bridge devices, can you elaborate?

Comment: If you didn't understand the comment about bridges you can ignore it.  (It is possible to create a switch on a Linux box by bridging multiple NICS)

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I missed here was /etc/hosts file - there was a wrong address for localhost on intel atom machine. After we fixed that, network connection was back to normal.